# What is a "microglot"?

Tags: meaning

Austin ([1956](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~francisp/NewPhil448/AustinPlea56.pdf)):

> Much, of course, of the amusement, and of the instruction, comes in drawing the coverts of the microglot, in hounding down the minutiae, and to this I can do no more here than incite you.

What is a "microglot"? And what is meant by "drawing the coverts of the microglot"?

Answer (score 2):

@Greybeard's analysis of the etymologies and evolutions of the terms that make up this expression is, as always, thorough and illuminating.

I'd like to add information about where they are actually in current usage.

*Microglot* is a term that is apparently used frequently by what I'd call "language hobbyists", who seriously pursue languages and linguistics either in the context of or outside their professional careers. There are a number of online communities, including the [Polyglot Conference](https://www.polyglotconference.com/history.html), where people who love learning about languages congregate and share research they've pursued. In these communities, *microglot* seems to be [commonly used](https://speakingfluently.com/2016/12/17/breathing-life-into-language/) to describe people who study languages that are endangered or whose use is localized to small communities or regions. It's still unclear to me whether J.L. Austin actually coined the term in [A Plea for Excuses](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~francisp/NewPhil448/AustinPlea56.pdf), or whether it had been used previously.

*Draw the coverts* is an expression taken from [fox-hunting terminology](https://www.huntingact.org/hunting/hunting-terms/). (See also [Fox Hunting Life](https://www.foxhuntinglife.com/ask-experts/2131-how-the-huntsman-draws-covert).)

A *covert* is a thicket or other naturally formed configuration where a fox might take shelter. It's pronounced "cover". When hounds search through a covert to find a fox and get it to emerge, it's called "drawing the covert" or "drawing covert".

With this information, I come to roughly the same conclusion as Greybeard regarding the meaning of Austin's phrase in the OP's question about *drawing the coverts of the microglot*. It's an elegant way of characterizing the activity of searching for and ultimately extracting the most elusive and intricate features of language, an activity that perhaps leads to the same joy and fascination experienced by people who study obscure languages not yet explored.

Answer (score 0):

**-glot**, combined form

**Etymology**: < ancient Greek -γλωττος (in e.g. ancient Greek πολύγλωττος polyglot adj., ἀνθρωπόγλωττος (see anthropoglot n.), Hellenistic Greek δίγλωττος diglot adj. and n.) < ancient Greek γλῶττα, Attic form of γλῶσσα **tongue, language**.

> Earliest in the mid 17th cent. in the borrowings polyglot adj. and polyglot n. An early formation within English is apparently shown by tetraglot adj. (compare also tetraglottical adj. at tetraglot adj. Derivatives).
>
> **1. Forming adjectives designating a person who speaks or knows the number or quantity of languages indicated by the first element, or a text written in the specified number of languages, as biglot adj., monoglot adj., panglot adj., etc.**
>
> **2**. Forming nouns denoting a person who speaks or knows the number or quantity of languages indicated by the first element, as monoglot n., pantoglot n., etc.

**microglot** is thus an invented word = micro + glot - the smallest (or most fundamental) nuance of language and or meaning

> **Covert** (n.) = cover, a place of protection or concealment:
>
> OED 2. **a. That which serves for concealment, protection, or shelter; a hiding-place, shelter; = cover**.
>
> 1692   J. Ray Wisdom of God (ed. 2) ii. 87   They did all creep out of their Holes and Coverts.
>
> 1874   G. Bancroft Hist. U.S. X. xxii. 463   No thicket offered covert, no swamp a refuge from cavalry.

**To draw:**

OED >- **I**. Of simple traction.

> - In the general sense. (The most general word for this; other words, partly synonymous, as drag, haul, trail, tug, imply drawing in a particular manner or with special force.)
>
> **1. a. trans. To cause (anything) to move toward oneself by the application of force; to pull.**

and thus, in this case, pulling away the "covert".

*Much, [...] comes in drawing the coverts of the microglot,* = Much, [...] arrives by the pulling away of the hiding places of the smallest (or most fundamental) nuance of language and or meaning.